# Unity editor capture "hold mouse down and move" event

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating a simple tilemap editor extention in unity because the default one lacks a lot of functionality my project needs. I am inheriting EditorWindow.
When holding the left mouse button and dragging the mouse i want to place tiles in the scene (in editor mode).

The picture below illustrates what behavior i want.

[image]:

The problem i face is how to recognize this event. This is the function for handling mouse input that i use:

```
void HandleMouseInput() {
    Event e = Event.current;
    switch (e.type) {
    case EventType.MouseDown:
        if (e.button == 0) PlaceTile();
        break;
    case EventType.MouseMove:
        Debug.Log("Moving");
        Debug.Log(e.button); // <-- always show 0 (left click) even though mouse is not clicked.
        break;
    }
}
```

The first case (single tile placement) works as expected. But i fail to capture the "left mouse button held down" event. I can capture a mouse move event `EventType.MouseMove` but i then need whether there was a left click. According to unity docs, `e.button == 0` indicates a left click (which works as expected in the first switch case). But in the second case `e.button` is always 0, regardless of what mouse button is clicked. There is a `EventType.MouseDrag` aswell but it seems to only trigger when you select a gameobject in the scene and drag it.

In Unity, when holding down the left mouse button and moving the mouse the default behavior seems to be creating a selection box:

[image]

Or dragging the entire scene if the hand icon is selected in the top left corner of the editor.

Essentially i want to capture this event and override the result with my own functionality.

EDIT: I think i could solve this by creating a custom tool https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorTools.EditorTool.html

Comment: I might be completely wrong as usual but I don't think that it is possible to overwrite a Unity built-in behavior. The thing is that the whole click and selection drag might be already handled before the events are even passed on to your custom script so it would not have any chance to intercept it

Comment: @derHugo Maybe so but i think i managed to come up with something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alright so instead of inheriting EditorWindow i created a custom tool TileTool and put all the logic in there.

In its OnToolGUI (OnGUI equivalent?) i can disable the box selection:

```
HandleUtility.AddDefaultControl(GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive));
```

And automagically the event `EventType.MouseDrag` is captured correctly and i achieve the desired effect.

The whole script:

```
[EditorTool("Tile Tool")]
class TileTool : EditorTool
{
    // Serialize this value to set a default value in the Inspector.
    [SerializeField]
    Texture2D icon;



    public override GUIContent toolbarIcon =>
        new GUIContent() {
            image = icon,
            text = "Tile Tool",
            tooltip = "Tile Tool"
        };


    public override void OnToolGUI(EditorWindow window) {
        HandleUtility.AddDefaultControl(GUIUtility.GetControlID(FocusType.Passive));
        HandleMouse();
    }

    void HandleMouse() {
        Event e = Event.current;
        switch (e.type) {
            case EventType.MouseDown:
                if (e.button == 0) ApplyLeftClickTool();
                break;
            case EventType.MouseDrag:
                if (e.button == 0) ApplyLeftClickTool();
                break;
        }
    }



    void ApplyLeftClickTool() {
        switch (TilemapEditor.Instance().ActiveTool) {
        case TilemapEditor.TileTool.BRUSH:
                PlaceTile();
                break;
        case TilemapEditor.TileTool.ERASER:
                EraseTile();
                break;
        }
    }

    void PlaceTile() {
        GameObject prefab = TilemapEditor.Instance().Selected;
        GetTilemap().Place(prefab, MouseInWorld());
    }

    void EraseTile() {
        GetTilemap().Erase(MouseInWorld());
    }

    PrefabTilemap GetTilemap() {
        PrefabTilemap tilemap = FindObjectOfType<PrefabTilemap>();
        if (tilemap == null) {
            GameObject tilemapGO = new GameObject("Tilemap");
            tilemap = tilemapGO.AddComponent<PrefabTilemap>();
            tilemap.Init();
        }
        return tilemap;
    }

    Vector2 MouseInWorld() {
        return HandleUtility.GUIPointToWorldRay(Event.current.mousePosition).origin;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah that looks cool! Good to know that apparently there **is** a way to catch the default behavior.